# What are the documentation that a QA should know apart from Test Plan?

Tags: manual-testing, qa-role, documentation, qa-process

Test Plan, Test Strategy, Test Case documents, test log, test summary report are some example of QA documentations. During the testing life cycle is there any other documentation that a QA should know about it?

Answer (score 1):

First, every team will be different and require a different amount of documentation...if any!

Let's discuss why zero to limited documentation tends to be "normal."

1. The [Agile Manifesto](https://agilemanifesto.org/) states:

> Working software over comprehensive documentation

A lot of people believe this to mean that "no documentation is needed" which is an incorrect interpretation. But, it's common. This manifesto was authored in 2001 and has been a guiding influence on software development since, rightly or wrongly.

> Responding to change over following a plan

This is another point of the manifesto regarding documentation. Docs may feel "set in stone" or "unchangeable," so it's perceived as a need to be flexible over a comprehensive documented plan.

2. "We don't have time to write documentation." Similar to the Agile Manifesto, a lot of teams choose not to write documentation because they perceive to not have time to do so. This can often put non-dev/non-coder roles in a bind since they often rely on documentation. This can also come up as an excuse for  engineers as they "don't like or want to write docs."
3. Why do we need test docs if the tests are automated? This comes up a lot. If a team uses test automation, a lot of testing docs seem duplicative effort. Documents may be useful initially, but then become obsolete once automation is created.
4. Any other reason. Fact is, there are a lot of reasons teams don't do documentation of any kind, not just with QA/testing.

What are some reasons to have documentation?

1. You'll forget things as time progresses.
2. It helps new team members get up to speed.
3. It helps other non-coding roles understand the system.
4. Certain industries need documentation. Think healthcare, legal, aerospace, insurance, etc.
5. Some jurisdictions and government entities have laws, standards (like IEEE standards), and statutes that require documentation.
6. Any other reason. Just like with reasons to not create documentation, there are numerous reasons to create documentation, sometimes that means only for yourself.

For QA, some teams require the use of a Test Case Management System (TCMS), so you'll be adding test cases and test plans there.

For other teams, there is only 1 QA on the feature dev team, so some flexibility on what docs are created is there. In this case, a TCMS maybe too rigid, and an old-school approach of using a spreadsheet for test cases will suffice, especially if you then automate those tests! The spreadsheet is then seen as temporary.

Where you maintain documentation is usually in a project management system. Lots of teams use the Atlassian Suite (Jira, Confluence), Asana, Monday, Notion, etc. So, get familiar with these.

The most used form of documentation for QA is a bug report. Learn to write good bug tickets; get the team to use a template if not already in use!

One piece of advice I wish I knew sooner, keep a blog! Start a blog and write things you learn about. This will help you over the course of your career!

Don't get too caught up on this, but definitely understand what is required for your team/company!